# Ejemplo maestro-detalles en vistas genericas de django

Tags: html, django

soy nuevo en django estoy intentando crear una vista cabecera-detalle como en el caso de las facturas donde debes agregar varios productos con una misma cabecera, es posible crear con el admin.

sin embargo no logro realizar lo mismo con vistas basadas en clases, algún link de ejemplo?
imagen de ejemplo de mi objetivo final.
con vistas basadas en clases:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una Vista **Mixins** que tenga unos parámetros y luego esos parámetros usarlos en todas las demás vistas que tengas.

Si puedes explicar mejor el termino **maestro-detalle** seria muy bueno.

Comment: Hola ,gracias por responder! podrías revisar la actualización de la pregunta, Gracias!